# How to get a replacement mounting plate?

Tags: tripod, repair-parts

I came across a free tripod with no mounting plate and no identifying logos. Yes, it is probably a cheap tripod which will only serve temporarily until getting a real one.

Is there a way to find a replacement mounting plate through measurements or is the tripod a loss?

[image]

Comment: If you are referring to a quick-release plate that mounts on your camera, there are many types, please post a picture.

Comment: Can the tripod head be unscrewed as a separate unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheap tripods typically use compatible quick-release plates.  Search for **"universal tripod quick release"** on your favorite online shopping or auction site.

[image: universal quick release]

If the "universal" plate doesn't fit, you're unlikely to find one that's the right size.  The tripods are too cheap for the manufacturers to sell custom-fitted plates separately.  The scheme appears to be to get people to buy new tripods when the plate is lost or broken.

- You could try shaving off a bit to get it to fit.  If you have a carving knife and know how to use it safely, that would be the way to go.  Sanding is also an option, but keep a vacuum cleaner handy to avoid getting dust everywhere.
- You may be [better off](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/186789/etymology-of-throw-good-money-after-bad) adding it to the growing collection of tripods with missing quick-release plates at your local thrift store.  You may be able to find a sturdier tripod in their collection that will work with a "universal" plate.

Cheap tripods tend to be made of aluminum with additional struts across the legs.  (See [Is there any benefit in tripods that are braced around a center post?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/105410/75526))

Comment: Thank you! The universals look so different/bulky that I thought I was finding the wrong thing.

Comment: What's important are that the length and width fit.  Some listings give dimensions, so you can check measurements.  The height is less important because they're tapered and will still lock.  If the universal plate doesn't fit, you can take it with you while searching for a better tripod.  (I've seen "pro" tripods for cheap just because they're missing the plate.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the photo in the question, it looks like a Manfrotto RC2 plate or third-party clone will fit it. The most basic RC2 plate is the [Manfrotto 200PL-14](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008I2175E). It's sometimes listed as a 200PL.

[image]

There are also many [generic plates](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QKVBPCM) made by other manufacturers that fit the manfrotto RC2 receiver.

Comment: That plate will probably be worth more than the whole tripod.

Comment: $14? You can get generics for $7-8.